# ValidationMessageFor not working as expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, validation

I am trying to add validations on my View. But I am unable to access the property inside `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(?)`

My View

```
@model IEnumerable<Entity.Employee>

<div class="jumbotron">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Employee", FormMethod.Post))
    {


        <label>Name</label>
        <input id="txtName" type="text" name="EmployeeName" class="btn btn-default" />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.   //not able to get the Name property


        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
    }
</div>
```

Employee Class

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter name")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Employee employee, string EmployeeName)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            employee.Name = EmployeeName;
            repository.SaveRole(role);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return View(employee);
        }
    }
```

I am not sure what have I missed or is it because the View is Strongly couple to `IEnumerable<Type>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view has defined model of type `IEnumerable<Entity.Employee>`. This stands for multiple employees. You should change your model declaration to

```
@model Entity.Employee
```

Comment: i am unable to execute a foreach statement then

Comment: There is no foreach shown in your code. If you want to have both list of Employees and form to create a new employee in the same view, you should create a view model with new employee field and list of employees.

Comment: can u demonstrate shortly in your answer.